# Prove that if $x^1,\dots,x^m$ are linearly independent then $C = \text{cone}(\{x^1,\dots,x^m\})$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $X = \{x^1,\dots,x^m\}$ be a set of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Superscripts are indices, not powers)

Prove that its conic hull $C=\text{cone}(X)$ is closed.

---

**ATTEMPT**

I am attempting to use Caratheodory's theorem for cones in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

> Every nonzero vector $x \in \text{cone}(X)$ can be written as a positive combination of at most $n$ elements of $X$.

I interpreted this symbolically as,
$$
   \forall (x \neq 0)\in \text{cone}(X), \;\; x = \sum_{i\,=\,1}^{m} \alpha_i  x^i, \;\;\; (\alpha_i>0).
$$

I chose $m$ to be the smallest integer for which $x$ is obtained (making $x^i$ linearly independent).

I am not sure how to prove closedness. I have attempted defining a sequence $x_k \in C$ and tried proving that $x_k \to x \in C$. But I am failing. I am not allowed to use polyhedral cones. So I am really stuck on how to prove closedness.

I am aware that any nonnegative combination of $x^i$ will be contained in $C$, but I am not sure how this would help.

Please, any insight is grealy appreciated.

Comment: If $x^k := \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i^k x^i \in \text{cone}(X)$ and $x^k \to x$, then it suffices to show the sequence $(\alpha_i^k)_k$ converges to some $\alpha_i$ for each $i$, in which case $x = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i x^i$ and must belong to the cone. I don't know if this approach works though.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did, but I am not sure if I am forcing the result in a wishful thinking kind of way, or if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define $m$ in two different ways. I will use $m$ as the cardinality of the linearly independent set you are given.

Let $x^k := \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i^k x^i \in \text{cone}(X)$ (where $\alpha_i^k \ge 0$) and suppose $x^k \to x$.

Since the $x^k$ lie in the subspace $\text{span}\{x^1, \ldots, x^m\}$, the limit $x$ must also lie in this subspace, since finite-dimensional subspaces are closed.

Since $x^1, \ldots, x^m$ are linearly independent, there exist unique $\alpha_i$ such that $x = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i x^i$.

It suffices to then show $\alpha_i^k \overset{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \alpha_i$ for each $i$, since that would imply $\alpha_i \ge 0$ for all $i$.

---

Suppose $\alpha_1^k \not\to\alpha_1$. Let $v$ be the unit vector in $\text{span}\{x^1, \ldots, x^m\}$ that is orthogonal to $x^2, \ldots, x^m$ (e.g., Gram-Schmidt).
Then $\|x_k - x\|^2 \ge (\alpha^k_1 - \alpha_1)^2 \langle x^1, v \rangle^2$.
Since $\alpha^k_1 \not\to \alpha_1$, we cannot have $\|x_k - x\| \to 0$, a contradiction.

Reply to comment:  any vector $w$ can be written uniquely as $w = w_\| + w_\perp$ such that $w_\|$ is parallel to $v$ and $w_\perp$ is orthogonal to $v$. Then $\|w\|^2 = \|w_\|\|^2 + \|w_\perp\|^2 \ge \|w_{\|}\|^2$. Note also that $w_\| = \langle w, v \rangle v$ since $v$ is a unit vector.
I'm applying this fact to $w := x_k - x$ and noting that $v$ is orthogonal to $x^2, \ldots, x^m$.

Comment: Do we really need the $x^i$s to be linearly independent though

Comment: It can be proven that for dependent vectors too, by simply expressing their cone as a finite union of cones generated by independent vectors. And which this question proven, so is the cone generated by dependent vectors.

Comment: But my question is specifically proving it for independent vectors. Why is $\|x_k - x\|^2 \ge (\alpha^k_1 - \alpha_1)^2 \langle x^1, v \rangle^2$? (I have certain gaps in vector spaces)

Comment: @ex.nihil See my edit.

Comment: Damn. I would have never thought of this. Brilliant proof.